# How to enable precise location for apps in Windows Subsystem for Android?

Tags: android, windows-11, geolocation, side-loading

I have Windows Subsystem for Android + ADB + WSA Toolkit. I installed application called Moovit in order to know when my bus will arrive. Turns out location is incorrect when using this application on Windows Subsystem. How can I fix this issue? On regular Windows application the location shows correctly. Only on Android subsystem is this a problem.

Comment: Android was developed for device that have at least one of the following: Wifi, Cellular, GPS. using one of these Android can provide pretty accurate location data, but WSA for Android AFAIK don't provide any of this. Therefore your Windows location is more accurate than the Android location wich most likely bases purely on your internet IP address. The only way to change this would be if WSA for Android would provide virtual location data using Windows location API.

Comment: > The only way to change this would be if WSA for Android would provide virtual location data using Windows location API.
Is this possible atm?